# Port 21 will not open. status is closed. forward port 21 to new domains.

Tags: server, ftp

I am having a problem opening port 21 on my Linux Ubuntu server. No matter what i do, i can not get my status to change from closed to open. Here is a recent iptables command i used and the result

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
nmap -p21-22,25,80,443 CCR1
```

Starting Nmap 4.53 ( http://insecure.org ) at 2012-06-19 03:13 CDT
Interesting ports on CCR1.chennaichristianradio.com (5.10.69.98):

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE

21/tcp  closed ftp
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  closed smtp
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
```

I also used commands from the advise from this forum 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-open-ftp-port-21/

I need to open this for FTP access to the server, and ultimately I need to forward port 21 to 2 domains i am setting up. Thank you for any assistance you can provide
-Bob Swaggerty

Comment: Are you using any firewall software? if yes, What is it?

Comment: Do you actually have any software running on port 21 that will respond to the portscan? type:
`nc localhost 21` on that machine, does it connect the the ftp server?
if not. Check your ftp server settings

Answer (score 0):

Forward port 21 on your router's Port Forwarding page.

Is your ISP blocking port 21?

Do you use some firewall in your system. If you do, ensure port 21 is open in your firewall.

After doing that retry the procedures in the site you mentioned.

Comment: port 21 is open on my router, and in the firewall on the server.

Comment: Are you using a proxy ?